# how to insert value in map when it is declared in structure?

Tags: c++, dictionary, segmentation-fault, structure

```
struct try
{
    int elem;
    map<int , int *> mymap;
}; // simple structure containing int and a map
struct try * var; // pointer to try structure
var = (struct point *) malloc(sizeof(struct point )); 
var->mymap[1]=(int * )malloc(sizeof(int)); // want to add(1,pointer to integer)
```

Showing segmenation fault because of last line

Comment: maybe the first line should say 'struct point' instead of 'struct try' ?

Comment: also, it's c++, not c; better to use c++ memory management instead of malloc. perhaps you just need a map<int,int>; with no pointers at all ?

Comment: `struct try` generates an error for me. What is your compiler and compilation flags ?

Comment: `try` is a keyword. Your code is illegal. This cannot be what you're actually running, unless your compiler is absurdly non-compliant (in which case, we shall not be able to reliably help you anyway).

Comment: @Garf365 g++ and -Wall

Comment: Hum, strange I use same... have you added something specific to allow the use of try as a struct name ?

Comment: @Garf365 nopz, i have tried with other name also but result is same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `new` instead of `malloc` :

```
struct point
{
    int elem;
    map<int , int *> mymap;
}; // simple structure containing int and a map
point * var; // pointer to try structure
var = new point; 
var->mymap[1]=new int;
```

Indeed, `new` allocate memory and call constructor. Here, with `malloc` which only allocate memory, constructor of member `mymap` isn't called, and so `mymap` still uninitialized, so you get undefined behavior when you use it.

Don't write C-like code when you use C++ => `new`/`delete` instead of `malloc`/`free`

And I think it could be a good thing to add a destructor to your `struct` which will delete remaining  pointer in `mymap` to avoid memory leak

Finally, if you use C++11 or greater, take a look at smart pointer : `std::unique_ptr`, `std::shared_ptr`, or for older version of C++, equivalent class from boost smart pointer:

```
struct point
{
    int elem;
    map<int , std::shared_ptr<int>> mymap;
}; // simple structure containing int and a map
// for c++14 or greater:
auto var = std::make_unique<point>(); 
//or c++11:
std::unique_ptr<point> var(new point);
// for both
var->mymap[1]=std::make_shared<int>();
```

Comment: No, you shouldn't use `new` either. It's not 1990 any more!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit yes, of course, see my edit. But it's important to understant underlying basic operations

Comment: Understand them, sure. Use them? No.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit is my edit is good according your comment ?

Comment: @Garf365 working fine with 'new' rather than 'malloc'